# jquery not updating dropdown options - Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

i have two dropdowns

one is

```
<select data-placeholder="Menu" name="menu" required data-rel="chosen" required id="menu">
    <c:if test="${not empty menuList}">
        <optgroup label="Choose one from below">
            <c:forEach var="thisMenu" items="${menuList}">
                <option value="${thisMenu.id}" <c:if test="${menu.id == thisMenu.id}">selected</c:if>>${thisMenu.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </optgroup>
    </c:if>
</select>
```

and the second one is

```
<div class="controls">
    <select data-placeholder="Category" name="category" id="category" required data-rel="chosen" required>
        <c:if test="${not empty menu1.categories}">
            <optgroup label="Choose one from below">
                <c:forEach var="thisCategory" items="${menu1.categories}">
                    <option value="${thisCategory.id}" <c:if test="${categoryId == thisCategory.id}">selected</c:if>>${thisCategory.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </optgroup>
        </c:if>
    </select>
</div>
```

and my ajax call is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu').on('change', function() {
            var elt = document.getElementById("menu");
            var menuId = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
            alert("menuId : " + menuId);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/superadmin/product/ajaxupdatecategories",
                data: ({menu:menuId}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    alert("response : " + response.categoryList);
                    $("#category").get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $.each(response.categoryList, function(index, item) {
                        alert(index + " category : " + item.name);
                        $("#category").get(0).options[$("#category").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.id, item.name);
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    $("#category").get(0).options.length = 0;
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

the issue is that im getting new categories from ajax but the category dropdown options not changing. 
please correct me what im doing wrong.

Comment: Which of your `alert`s get triggered?

Comment: all of them, even the one inside $.each(...) that one shows me every single category in list.

Comment: [Here options are accessed differently](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-add-option-select-jquery/)

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @Adder no luck .

Comment: Maybe the `optgroup`s have to be accessed differently?